# How to kill that default login-page?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm using

```
Spring Security 4.0.
```

I tried the configuration:

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" 
                    access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" 
                default-target-url="/admin" 
                authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" 
                username-parameter="user"
                password-parameter="password" 
                login-processing-url="/login"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" logout-url="/logout" />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf/>
</http>
```

and when I try to get `login-page` I received the default spring-login-page. The method of a controller that was going to handle that request:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login")
public String renderLogin(){
    return "index";
}
```

wasn't even called. I just get the default-login-page:

[image]

But, if I tried to pass a request parameter, I mean try to get url like `localhost:8080/login?` then my login page will be rendered. What's wrong with that?

Comment: You don't need a controller, Spring Security is doing that. Also you are basically configuring the default `/login` is the default. If you want `index` then specify `index` in there and drop your controller.

Comment: @M.Deinum I want to customize the `/login` page. If it's not possible to do via a controller, how else I can do that?

Comment: Just as I mentioned... The `login-page` is the name of the view/jsp you want to render... In your case `index.jsp`. I strongly suggest a read of [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-form-and-basic) instead of trying to guess what properties are doing.

Comment: @M.Deinum I read [spring 4 security](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-http) because of the version I'm using. What it said was _`login-page` The URL that should be used to render the login page. Maps to the loginFormUrl property of the LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint. Defaults to "/login"._ Ok, it's  a URL, not just a `view/jsp` name as you said. Therefore it should be handled by controller method that could catch that URL. What's wrong? My goal is to make my login-page accessable by the `localhost:8080/projName/login` page.

Comment: Because, as I mentioned before, `/login` is the default and that will be processed always by Spring Security. You don't need a controller, the only thing yuor controller does is select the page. Just put the URL of the page in there. You have to make it something different then `/login`.

Comment: @M.Deinum _You have to make it something different then /login_ That's the key thing, thank you. It just wasn't mentioned in the documentation explicitly.

Comment: Well no but that is what is implied with being the default...

Comment: @M.Deinum But such a thing is totally unuseful, because in a production environemtn we always need to cusomize a login form. So we just cannot use the url _%host%/login_ as a login page, unless we want to use custom login-form, can we?